# Facebook Graph API POST to a comment to a Stream object

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post a comment to a status post on facebook.  I've figured out how to "like" existing comments using the following code:

$status = $facebook->api("/$id/likes", 'post');

How would I modify the code to post a comment to this status message instead of like.

I've tried this:
$status = $facebook->api("/$id/stream", 'post', "$comment");

but it returns this error:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I've also used "/$id/comments" instead of "/$id/stream", same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$facebook->api('/'.$POST_ID.'/comments','post',array('message' => $comment));` works for me. Make sure that you have `publish_stream` permissions and that you provide a proper Post ID of the status message.